# Como puedo pasar de un sitio a otro manteniendo login desdel sitio main?

Tags: php, aplicación-web, login

Intentare explicar lo mas claro posible.

Esoy desarrollando un sistema, que incluye varias apps dentro del sitio. El sitio principal controla la autentificacion del usuario y muestra las apps a las que el usuario puede acceder despues del LOGIN. Los datos del usuario se cargan en `$_SESSION['u']`.

Un intento de graficar.

Usuario X accede a `http://main.misitio.st` donde tiene una caja de login. Pasa el login y se crea `$_SESSION['u']` que contiene un `Array()` con valores: `IDusuario`, `IDSession`, (puedo poner la contraseña, aunque ahora mismo no esta). Cuando pasa el login, el sistema determina que X puede acceder a las apps *AP1*, *AP2*.

X da click en *AP2* y entonces accede a `http://ap2.misitio.st`.

Aqui es donde ocurre el problema porque `$_SESSION['u']` ya no existe para esta ultima URL.

Pudieran preguntarse porque cambiar el url y no poner que siempre cargue direcciones como `http://main.misitio.st/ap2/`. Todo pasa porque cada apps debe conservar total independencia, de manera que mañana la pueda sacar y poner como un sitio "*main*" a ella misma.

Una idea que se me ocurre. Poner `<a href="ap1.misitio.st/" + base64_encode($login+$paswd)">` y en el `init.php` de *AP2*, verificar si existe la session, si no existe, llamo `CheckValidAccess($log, $psw)`. Si X tiene derecho a acceder a *AP2*, lo dejo pasar, sino redirecciono a `http://main.misitio.st`.

El problema es que por algo no me gusta esta solucion. Si alguien pudiera darme ideas que me ayuden con el problema.

Saludos,
Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Y todas las aplicaciones comparten la misma base de datos? o tambien son independientes?

Comment: Gracias @jecorrales. No comparten. Existe db_main para la zona principal, con info relativa a los usuarios (IDuser, IDapps_aval). Existe db_app(x) con la info relativa a la aplicacion. Una tabla tb_user_apps que contiene el (IDuser, IDroles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configura

```
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime,$path,".domain.com")
```

> para que la sesión viva en todos los subdominios del dominio.

Comment: Hola. He puesto `if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
    session_set_cookie_params(3600, "/", ".misitio.st");
}` pero cuando entra a app1.misitio.st, en el mismo script que se lee al inicio, `$_SESSION['u']` dice que no existe.

Comment: ¿Dónde declaras $_SESSION['u']?, ¿Solo pasa con app1?

Comment: Hola Christian. Como ves le di solucionado a la respuesta de usar `session_set_cookie_params()`. Es que no me habia percatado de ponerlo siempre al inicio. En mi caso siempre llamo un script que reiniciar cada apps. Al cambia subdominio en la nueva apps (app1.misitio.st) debia ponerlo, y asi en cada (appx.misitio.st). Gracias por tu comentario.